# Best practice for naming unit and integration test methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, naming-conventions

I've recently inherited an application that is written by different people at different times and looking for guidance on how to standardize.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming NUnit:

```
[Test]
public void ObjectUnderTest_StateChanged_Consequence()
{
    Assert.That(tra_la_la);
}

[Test]
public void ObjectUnderTest_Behaviour_Consequence()
{
    Assert.That(tra_la_la);
}
```

for example:

```
[Test]
public void WifeIsTired_TakeWifeToDinner_WifeIsGrateful()
{
    Assert.That(tra_la_la);
}

[Test]
public void WifeIsTired_MentionNewGirlfriend_WifeGetsHalf()
{
    Assert.That(tra_la_la);
}
```

Comment: An alternative to this is MethodUnderTest_Scenario_Expectation. For example AddItem_EmptyCart_OneItemInCart(). This assumes one test fixture class per class under test.

Comment: @Ryan -- Your suggestion is what I ended up using.  It's also the recommendation of the book "the art of unit testing".

Answer (score 6):

I just write what it's for. It's not like you're going to have to type the names in anywhere else, so having a `testWibbleDoesNotThrowAnExceptionIfPassedAFrobulator` isn't a problem. Anything which is a test begins with 'test', obviously.

Comment: One up for using the Martin Fowler gobbledigook vocabulary

Answer (score 6):

There is no standard as such, different people/places will have different schemes. The important thing is you *stick* to a standard.

Personally I'm a fan of the following - example code in C#, but very close to Java, same rules apply:

```
[Test]
public void person_should_say_hello()
{
     // Arrange
     var person = new Person();
     // Act
     string result = person.SayHello();
     // Assert
     Assert(..., "The person did not say hello correctly!");
}
```

**Explicit**

The test name should give the name of the class under test. In this example, the class being tested is `Person`. The test name should also have the name of the method that is being tested. This way, if the test was to fail, you'll at least know where to look to solve it. I'd also recommend following the [AAA - Arrange, Act, Assert](http://agileinaflash.blogspot.com/2009/03/arrange-act-assert.html) rule, it will ensures your tests are easy to read and follow.

**Friendly fail messages**

When it comes to asserting a result/state, its useful to include an optional message. This makes it easier when a test fails, especially when run as part of a build process or via an external tool.

**Underscores**

The final (though optional) stance I follow is using underscores for tests names. While I'm no fan of underscores in production code, their use in test names is useful as test names are often much longer. Quickly glancing at a test name that uses underscores proves to be much more readable, though this is subjective and the source of much debate with regards unit testing practices.

**Integration Tests**

The same standards apply to integration tests, the only difference being the location of such tests *should* be separate from unit tests. In the example code above, the test class would be called `PersonTests` and located in a file called `PersonTests.cs`. The integration tests would be named in a similar manner - `PersonIntegrationTests`, located in `PersonIntegrationTests.cs`. The same project can be used for these tests, but ensure they are located in separate directories.

Answer (score 2):

It's instructive to look at BDD (behavioural driven development) and [this blog post](http://blog.dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/) in particular.

BDD is essentially focusing on components and what they *should* do. Consequently it impacts directly on how you name/structure your tests, and the code they use to set up conditions and validate. BDD allows not only the developers to read/write the tests, but non-technical members of the team (business analysts etc.) can contribute by specifying the tests and validating them.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across two good suggestions. Links here:

- [Unit Test Naming](https://slott-softwarearchitect.blogspot.com/2009/10/unit-test-naming.html)
- [Naming standards for unit tests](https://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html)
- [Unit Testing With at-should Annotation](https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Unit%20Testing%20With%20at-should%20Annotation)

Answer (score 1):

In that situation I'd probably find the naming convention that was used the most and refactor the rest of the code to use that.  If the one that was used the most is truly horrid, I'd still look to the existing code and try to find one that I could live with.  Consistency is more important than arbitrary conventions.

Comment: Its not an arbitrary convention I'm after, but a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

I use a `FunctionTestCondition` construct. If I have two methods, `Get` and `Set` I would maybe create the following test methods:

- `GetTest` being a positive test (everything is ok).
- `GetTestInvalidIndex` to test an invalid index being passed to the method.
- `GetTestNotInitialized` to test when the data is not inited before use.
- `SetTest`
- `SetTestInvalidIndex`
- `SetTestTooLargeValue`
- `SetTestTooLongString`

Answer (score 0):

Group your tests by setup, make a test class around this setup and name is with suffix Test or IntegrationTest. Using a test framework like [JUnit](http://junit.org/) or [TestNG](http://testng.org/) you can name your test methods as you want. I would name the method as what it tests, a sentence in camel case, not test prefix. The frameworks use a `@Test` annotation to mark a method as test.